# MUI TextField outline overlaps label

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I have a MUI TextField with  and with default settings all look good:

[image]

But if I size the font larger (see theme below) then the borderline overlaps the label:

[image]

```
function MyForm() {
return (
    <>
        <div>a</div>
        <div><TextField variant={'outlined'} label="Type something" value={'my value'}/></div>
    </>
);}


const themeOptions: ThemeOptions = {
components: {
    MuiInputLabel: {
        styleOverrides: {
            root: {
                fontSize: '1rem', // make labelfont bigger
            },
        },
    },
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two main aspects of the text field that impact the sizing of the notch in the outline and whether the label fits in that notch.

##### `InputLabel` sizing

When the label is up in the notch of the outline, that means `shrink=true` which by default occurs when the input has focus or already has a value. The [relevant styles applied](https://github.com/mui/material-ui/blob/v5.13.0/packages/mui-material/src/InputLabel/InputLabel.js#L116) in the `shrink` case are `transform: 'translate(14px, -9px) scale(0.75)'`, so the label text will 0.75 * the size of the label when not in the `shrink` state.

##### notch sizing

The space for the notch in the outline is controlled by the size of a `legend` element within a `fieldset` element within the `OutlinedInput`. The [relevant styles for that `legend`](https://github.com/mui/material-ui/blob/v5.13.0/packages/mui-material/src/OutlinedInput/NotchedOutline.js#L38) element are `fontSize: '0.75em'`. This means that the legend space will be based on the size of the label using a font size that is 0.75 * the font size of the `OutlinedInput`. Note that this legend does NOT display the label. It contains a copy of the label text to control the sizing, but it has `opacity: 0` in its styles so that it is invisible apart from its block creating a notch in the outline. The `InputLabel` element then places the label text in that same location.

An important thing to realize then is that the default notch sizing is dependent on the font size of the `OutlinedInput` being the same as the `InputLabel` font size.

There are two different options for how to fix the size of the notch:

1. Change the font-size for the `OutlinedInput` to be the same as the label, so that the text of the input will match the non-shrink label size.

```
import * as React from "react";
import TextField from "@mui/material/TextField";
import { createTheme, ThemeProvider } from "@mui/material/styles";

const labelFontSize = "1.25rem";
export default function TextFieldWithLargerLabel() {
  const theme = createTheme({
    components: {
      MuiInputLabel: {
        styleOverrides: {
          root: {
            fontSize: labelFontSize
          }
        }
      },
      MuiOutlinedInput: {
        styleOverrides: {
          root: {
            fontSize: labelFontSize
          }
        }
      }
    }
  });
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <TextField id="outlined-basic" label="Type something" />
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit text field label size]

2. If you want to have the label size bigger than the input text size, then you can change the font-size of the legend that controls the notch to match the shrink label size.

```
import * as React from "react";
import TextField from "@mui/material/TextField";
import { createTheme, ThemeProvider } from "@mui/material/styles";

const labelFontSize = "1.25rem";
export default function TextFieldWithLargerLabel() {
  const theme = createTheme({
    components: {
      MuiInputLabel: {
        styleOverrides: {
          root: {
            fontSize: labelFontSize
          }
        }
      },
      MuiOutlinedInput: {
        styleOverrides: {
          root: {
            "& > fieldset > legend": {
              fontSize: `calc(0.75 * ${labelFontSize})`
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  });
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <TextField id="outlined-basic" label="Type something" />
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit text field label size]

Answer (score 0):

The problem comes from the fact that it only increases the size of the label but not the size of the input.

To solve this, you can do the following:

```js
import * as React from "react";

import FormControl from "@mui/material/FormControl";
import InputLabel from "@mui/material/InputLabel";
import OutlinedInput from "@mui/material/OutlinedInput";

export default function MyForm() {
  return (
    <FormControl>
      <InputLabel htmlFor="input-outlined" sx={{ fontSize: 20 }}>
        Type something
      </InputLabel>
      <OutlinedInput
        id="input-outlined"
        label="Type something"
        sx={{ fontSize: 20 }}
      />
    </FormControl>
  );
}
```